# Как вернуть все данные таблицы после выполнения фильтрации и поиска?

Tags: запрос, sql

На форму расположены ADOQuery,DataSource, Данные выводятся в DBGrid. После фильтрации или поиска, найденые данные остаются в таблице.
Собственно вопрос как вернуть все данные которые были в таблице до фильтрации и поиска? по нажатию на кнопку

Comment: Так?

    ADOQuery.Filter:='';

Comment: Нет это не помогло)

Comment: Что, если сделать первоначальный запрос с этими данными из базы? Но по идее, сброс фильтра должен позволить снова отобразить всё, что было.

Comment: @Artem1992s Код накладывания фильтра или поиска покажите. Гадать мы можем до бесконечности в принципе.

Comment: Всё уже решил вопрос)
Begin  
if edt56.Text = '' then Exit;
  if Pos('where', ADOQuery1.SQL.Text) > 0 then
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Delete(ADOQuery1.SQL.Count-1);
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('where ÃîäÂûïóñêà LIKE "'+edt56.Text+'%"');
  ADOQuery1.Open; 
end;

Comment: @Artem1992s, про параметры вы слышали что-нибудь? Вот [тут][1] пример посмотрите. 

[1]:http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/ADOQuery_(Delphi)

Answer (score 1):

```
ADoQuery.Filtered := False;
```